# How to change a Default Site Owner Group (not classic)

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, site

I don't know why, but the originator of one of our SharePoint sites set the owner group to our general pool group that has all employees.

I want to set the access permission requests to be sent to the site group who manage the site, but my only options are an email address or the site owner group (which is the general pool).

I cannot find where to change this in the non classic view. Unfortunately, the site template they used has no option to switch to classic.

Besides, I am trying to learn to new experience

Thank you for any assistance you can provide! <(_ _*)> You have my gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you were asking how to change the Site Owner Group.
You just need to access the original permsetup page for the given site.
Form the URL like this:
https://spTennant.sharepoint.com/sites/pathToSite/_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx

From there you can redefine the groups for visitors, members or owner to existing groups or create new groups.

[Once that's done you'll need to follow KB article to ensure the new Owner Group has FullControl to the AccessRequests list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-access-denied-to-access-requests-list-or-request-approval-failed-when-you-process-a-pending-request-in-sharepoint-online-3ec71fe1-9111-4a4c-84a5-bdfe05c2e558?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

HTH,
SM

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using a Modern site.

You can click Settings -> Site permissions -> Advanced permissions settings

[image]

[image]

In the permission management page, click Access Request settings.

[image]

[How to manage access requests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3)